# Junit test for model class

Tags: java, junit, mockito

This question is about best practice rather than any issues or problem. I have a service method below that I am trying to test. myDAO is DAO class that will be injected and has all database call code.

```
public List<MyObject> getMyObject(String inputParameter){
    List<MyObject> objectList = myDAO.getObjectList(inputParameter);
    return objectList 
}
```

And my Junit test case using mockito is

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyClassTest{
    @InjectMocks
    MyClass myClass;

    @Mock
    MyDAO myDAO;

    private MyObject myObj;
    private List<MyObject> objList;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {  
        myObj = new MyObject();
        myObj.setQuantity(10);
        //I am calling all setter method to prepare myObj here
        objList = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
        objList.add(myObj); 

        when(myDAO.getObjectList(any(InputParameter.class))
                                                    .thenReturn(objList);    
    }


    @Test
    public void testGetMyObject(){

        List<MyObject> result =  myClass.getMybject(null);
        assertThat(" Quantity should return 10", result.getQuantity(), is(10));
        // and all asserts....
    }
```

Everything is fine and working. My main problem here is MyObject is a modal class with 200 parameter.

Now for code coverage I have to call 200 setter methods while preparing objects  and asserts 200 getter methods for junit test. I think this is not a good idea. what is better practice and how to cover this kind of modal class on unit test code coverage.

Comment: 200 fields. Interesting...

Comment: *My main problem here is MyObject is a modal class with 200 parameter.* Yes, I would say that that is *indeed* your main problem. If you have a entity with 200 properties then you clearly need to remodel.

Comment: don't bother testing models, since it should not have any logic in it. Focus on increasing your coverage in your DAO and services.

Comment: @M.leRutte any suggestion how can this be remodeled ? I tried to break this modal class to several classes and create one modal class with these classes as parameter. But at the end story is same.

Comment: @Todoy There is no way I can have 95% code coverage ignoring this model class.

Comment: @user8710021 if code coverage is the only thing you are looking for remove the unused getters and setters.

Comment: @Todoy that didn't answer my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There has always been huge debate on best practice for writing unit test cases. So for this kind of question, there will not be definitive answer.  For me writing test cases for getter and setter just to make code coverage percentage high is stupid. But Sometime your choice and your preference doesn't count.

Despite your code need refactoring, you can use some API that makes your job easier. SmartUnit is one of those, that you can use to test your POJO. These API allows you to write only few lines and behind the scene, cover all your getter/setter code coverage.

Answer (score 5):

1) 200 fields defined in a single class implies a real design problem.
Even a model class has not to own so many fields.

2) Your test actually tests nothing.
The single logic of your test is :

```
List<MyObject> objectList = myDAO.getObjectList(inputParameter);
```

but you mock the invocation of the DAO.
So finally, you test only the getter/setter methods.

I think that testing this class in an unitary point of view is not a great deal.
You should rather test this class in the frame of an integration test where the DAO would not be mocked.

Besides, if you test it from a top layer, you could also have a cleaner way to set the fixture of the test as client classes doesn't populate all these unitary data.
It could be provided from a fixture SQL script for example.

Comment: I know I am testing nothing here. But how would you write junit test for this kind of service methods as code coverage will count all lines no matter if this is getter/setter or any other logical piece of code.

Comment: What you should do is abandon measuring code coverage percentage.  It's not a useful metric, especially when it comes to classes with lots of getters and setters.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem that is beyond my power where I am working.

Comment: Who told you you have to have 95% code coverage?  It's a completely stupid thing to demand.  If it's your boss, then I'd suggest you ask him/her whether he/she would prefer you to spend your time coding tests that have absolutely no value whatsoever, or coding features that might be useful to the customer.

Comment: @Dawood ibn Kareem  Agree totally with you but unfortunately, some managers in some companies prefer dashboards with red and green indicators than a person with knowledge that may explain things that they don't want or cannot understand.

Comment: Lets forget that part. My question is what is good practice for writing unit test cases for this sort of service class.

Comment: Good practice is not doing it.

Comment: @user8710021 In most of coverage tool, you may configure them to mark some classes to ignore in the coverage. Why not ignore this class and explain reasons in a comment ?

Comment: `MyClassTest` does not test `MyClass`.  To test `MyClass` verify `myDAO` was invoked with a specific parameter value.

Comment: So in summary, don't bother testing this kind of class and ignore it. Anybody have any other thoughts other then this conclusion?

Comment: @user8710021 If this class is tested in an integration test from a top layer, this code is in big part covered.

Comment: @davidxxx Sorry but I am not familiar with integration test. Is it something different to junit testing.

Comment: To satisfy {insert favorite profanity} managers who only see metrics with no context, write a class named something like `SimpleBeanTester` which uses reflection to discover all the fields and call the setter/getter with randomly generated values.

Comment: Bottom line - aim to test 100% of the LOGIC, and nothing else.  Most getters and setters contain no logic

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/48237/what-is-an-integration-test-exactly

Answer (score 0):

Writing the test cases for models just for the code coverage is definitely not a good idea. If that is all about the code coverage report then you can add configuration to ignore the model package from report generation and also from the execution of the junit. This will increase the code coverage of your application.

Answer (score -2):

Why not just use lombok to generate the getter/setter boiler plate code. This way you dont have to worry about coverage percentages on POJO classes.

Comment: JaCoCo will cover lombok annotations